# how to report turtles state one tick before the simulation ends in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I've made a population model in Netlogo where the simulation stops when all my turtles have died OR the number of 300 ticks is reached. I need to report (or write to a file) the mean state of my turtles (turtle-own variables) one tick before the simulation ends. It would be easy if all simulations will run to 300 ticks, but in most cases the simulation ends before this happens (all turtles die). How can I achieve this? The death of the turtles is conditioned to either their "lifetime" runs out or to a stochastic probability of dying, so I can't predict when will this happen, and I need to know whether the last turtle died due to their lifetime running out or due to the probability worked against the turtle. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you played around with BehaviorSpace at all? It works pretty well for means and sums etc. You can easily make BehaviorSpace experiments to export whatever reporters you set up to a .csv spreadsheet or table, whether you want reports at the end of your simulation or at each tick. For a simple example, if I want to know the mean x-coordinate of my turtles, I can set up the reporter using `to-report`:

```
to-report mean-xcor
  let xlist ( [xcor] of turtles )
  report mean xlist
end
```

Then, I can use Behavior Space (Tools > Behaviour Space) to [set up an experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWHa.jpg) that writes that mean xcor for all turtles at either each tick or only at the end of a run. The tool also allows you to set up multiple parameterizations of your simulation and compare results with different treatments- it's really handy! You can get creative with what you report in order to have the output be what you need. For your specific case, you could just make sure that your experiment is recorded at each tick.

You could also do this manually and with a little more control if you prefer. You can create a file and header during your setup using something like:

```
to setup-turtle-reporting
  file-open "turtle_details_out.csv"
  file-type (word "tick, who, xcor, ycor \n")
  file-close
end
```

That sets up a .csv file in your model folder that has the column headers tick, who, xcor, and ycor. Then, during each tick you can have turtles write the appropriate variables to that same file:

```
to turtle-report
  file-open "turtle_details_out.csv"
  ask turtles [
    file-type (word ticks ", " who ", " xcor ", " ycor "\n" )
  ]
  file-close  
end
```

This option gives you a bit more control in some ways, but is fiddlier. You will have to also play around with `file-delete` or manually delete/rename the file as you complete different simulations, as `file-type` will append to the existing file rather than overwriting it.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I do use Behavior Space, but I have a combinatorial of 2x2x5x10x10 (without considering replicates), so I wanted to avoid saving the entire run and save only one tick. But your suggestion is probably the way I'll go because I can't find other way to solve this problem ;)

Comment: Fair enough! In that case, maybe it would work to set something up so that at the start of every tick, all turtles store their variables in temporary global list/variable. Then, if within that same tick the number of turtles hits zero, export that list to file.